# How to get module to "extend" into my Model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

#### lib/modules/sport_time.rb

```
module SportTime

    def to_race_time(secs)
      m = (secs/60).floor
      s = (secs - (m*60))
      t = sprintf("%02d:%.2f\n",m,s)
      return t
    end

    def time_to_float(tim)
      dirty = tim.to_s
      min, sec = dirty.split(":")
      seconds = (min.to_i * 60) + sec.to_f
      seconds.round(4)
    end

end

class Event
  extend SportTime
  before_save :sporty_save

  private

  def sporty_save
    self.goal_time = self.class.time_to_float(goal_time)
  end
end
```

#### events.rb Model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_presence_of :course, :goal_time, :race_length, :user_id
   attr_accessible :course, :goal_time, :race_length, :user_id
   belongs_to :user
end
```

---

**Problem:** When I try to create an Event with a goal_time of "1:15.55" (string), instead of being saved as 75.55 (float), it's being saved as 1.0 (float)...so whatever I'm doing with the class mixin clearly isn't working.

I'm pretty new to working with modules, so I'm having a tough time figuring out why I can't get it to I'm doing wrong here. Any help appreciated, thanks.

*Note: the float-to-string conversion for the view does work.*

Comment: What's the column type in the database?

Comment: Also print returns nil, not the string passed to it, so I don't thing you want to be using that here.

Comment: column type is float...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module SportTime
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :sporty_save
  end

  private
  def sporty_save
    self.goal_time = time_to_float(goal_time)
  end

  def to_race_time(secs)
    m = (secs/60).floor
    s = (secs - (m*60))
    sprintf("%02d:%.2f\n",m,s)
  end

  def time_to_float(tim)
    dirty = tim.to_s
    min, sec = dirty.split(":")
    seconds = (min.to_i * 60) + sec.to_f
    seconds.round(4)
  end

end


class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   include SportTime
   validates_presence_of :course, :goal_time, :race_length, :user_id
   attr_accessible :course, :goal_time, :race_length, :user_id
   belongs_to :user
end
```

And make sure your lib directory is autoloaded or you can place your mixins under models/mixin directory in Mixin::SportTime module

Comment: The methods in the module will be available only to instances of the class, not the class. That exactly is the difference between `include` and `extend`. Using `ActiveSupport::Concern` does not change this.

Comment: That exactly what you need for before_save))

Comment: Hmmm, right. Now I look like an asshole, don't I? Here, have an upvote.